# Test result of axios return

Tags: javascript, object, if-statement

I am testing result of axios error such way:

```
            .catch((error) => {
                if (!error.response || !error.response.data || !error.response.data[0] || !error.response.data[0].err_code) {
                    reject(999);
                } else {
                    reject(error.response.data[0].err_code);
                }
            });
```

Sometimes error object contains all segments  error.response.data[0], sometimes not. Is there any way to test existence of error.response.data[0] segment as my example, but not so verbose?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solutions, that work well for me. I use so called "Optional chaining" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) , thanks to Berk Korkcuoglu.
Here is my code:

```
            .catch((error) => {
                if (!error?.response?.data?.[0]?.err_code) {
                    reject(999);
                } else {
                    reject(error.response.data[0].err_code);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit compact is:

```
        .catch((error) => {
           reject(error?.response?.data?.[0]?.err_code || 999);
        });
```